# mysql select from multiple table with function

Tags: mysql

what is the prublem with this query

```
select reports.SUM( time1 ),
reports.created_by,
reports.id,
users.wage,
users.title
from reports,
users
where users.title = reports.created_by
and reports.created_date >= '1396/03/01'
and reports.created_date <= '1396/03/30'
GROUP BY created_by
ORDER BY created_by
```

## 1630 - FUNCTION reports.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: You only call it like this `SELECT SUM(reports.time1) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be ...

```
select SUM(reports.time1),
reports.created_by,
reports.id,
users.wage,
users.title
from reports,
users
where users.title = reports.created_by
and reports.created_date >= '1396/03/01'
and reports.created_date <= '1396/03/30'
GROUP BY created_by
ORDER BY created_by
```